# Can you explain the weird and inconsistent naming of functions in Python base libraries?

Tags: python, naming-conventions, standards

When I started learning Python I started loving it for how much more structured it was than PHP which has a lot of functions that do not mentally flow very well, but I've been noticing odd inconsistencies with no apparent reasoning in Python as well.

For example, in PHP there are [some functions for arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) that start with "array" in their name, some that don't, some that use underscores, some that shorten parts of their names down to a single character, etc. and they typically need to take an array as an argument rather than being a method of an array object.

In Python, there are a lot of single-word function names, but when it comes to multiple words I see an inconsistency.
For example, logging module methods with camelcase like `logging.StreamHandler()`, underscores in sys like `sys.base_prefix()` and just lower case with no separators like `os.expandvars()`.
As if that wasn't enough, there are function names like `os.path.splitext()` that eventually led to me posting this.

Why are they not all one type of convention?

```
logging.StreamHandler() # capitalize in case classes
sys.basePrefix()
os.expandVars()
os.path.splitText()
```

or even like this:

```
logging.stream_handler()
sys.base_prefix()
os.expand_vars()
os.path.split_text() # the original is actually "spli + text" in one word!
```

Is there any popular programming language out there that strictly adheres to conventions like in my example below?

```
some_value        # variable lower case separated by underscores (which allows them to appear descriptive)
someFunction()    # functions and methods camel case, first letter lower case (differentiates from variables while still readable and allows simple names like get() and send())
SomeObject()      # classes always start with capital letters and are camelcase (makes them stand out and above but appear closer to functions)
IMPORTANT_VALUE   # constants always upper case, separated by underscores (easily tell apart from anything else, while being the reverse case from normal variables)
```

So why does this happen and does something like my example ever happen to a significant extend in reality?

Comment: `tolist()` in Pandas really annoys me when everything else is `to_csv()` etc (granted not a base library). Now I've done griping with that; because people are human and humans lack consistency? I don't know what other answer there could be to "why does this happen?".

Comment: It's a bit too much in my opinion if you decide to go for a convention in your module but then decide to omit a letter for English words here and there and sometimes just go for no convention at all and just mash the words together in some way...
Otherwise, I'd be convinced that it really is typical of human creatures to float around their own consistency.

Comment: Ok, there is [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) that should be adhered to throughout python. It's applied inconsistently across a huge body of work from hundreds of people. I still don't get what answer would satisfy you here; it's inconsistent because people.

Comment: And PEP8 also addresses the question; often "because history" rather than "because people." See the section "A Foolish Consistency is the Hobgoblin of Little Minds."  That said, this question can't really be given a technical answer. The answer is "because they are." Same reason the plural of ox is oxen, not oxes. (As for a "popular" programming language that *strictly* adheres to the rules given, which are the PEP8 rules, no.)

Comment: `splitext` is not a weird short form of `split text`, but `split ext` (split extension), so it makes sense. Otherwise, I totally agree with the inconsistent naming in Python.

Comment: @roganjosh I also found it annoying, apparently this is "for compat with numpy, e.g. numpy.tolist is the standard method" https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8826#issuecomment-63182100

The .to_list() alias can be used since 0.24.0 https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the reason for these inconsistencies come about because Python developers value consistency within a single module as more important than consistency with the rest of the standard library.

As to why the modules within the standard library have varying naming conventions, many of these came about because of many reasons. The `os` module for example, most of the functions there are straightforward wrappers around function with the same name in C standard and system/POSIX libraries; to reduce friction between C and Python developers and to take advantage of developer's existing knowledge of POSIX, the C names have simply been used as-is for that module. There are functions in the `os` module that doesn't have a correspondence with C/POSIX functions, but to avoid internal inconsistency within `os` module, they also inherit the C naming convention.

If you want a more Pythonic version of the standard library, there are higher level wrappers for many of the functions in `os`, such as `subprocess` module and `pathlib`. These modules follow the PEP8 naming convention.

PEP8 specifies that classes are named with `CamelCase` and variables, functions, and attributes are named with `snake_case`, that explains the difference between `logging.StreamHandler` and `sys.base_prefix`.

And then there are libraries like XML/HTML DOM, which specifies function names that adheres more to JavaScript naming convention (XML and HTML DOM API were designed by the web standards people, which follows the tradition of JavaScript), or unittest which is designed based on Java's xUnit. Python decided to just adopt those existing naming conventions to exploit familiarities with people who are already familiar with the existing names, as the API are simply copied as-is.

> then decide to omit a letter for English words here and there

Most of the function names with omitted letters usually come from ancient C libraries, these were named back when text editors weren't as advanced and people want to save letters to minimise typing long variable names or when there are restrictive character limits on how long you can name things. Python and PHP inherit many of these names for the low level wrappers for these functions.

Python is often used as a glue language, which means it is often used to put together an application from libraries written in other languages, which has their own existing naming conventions. Renaming these established interfaces just to conform to Python's naming convention will just confuse people who are familiar with the established APIs for no good reason, as consistency with the established APIs are more important when reading documentations, while consistency with the rest of the standard library are pretty much just for aesthetics.

Answer (score -4):

That's a good question. I believe it is because people get to name them, so for some efficiency trumps readability, and others vise versa.